# How to change X axis to not be uniform scale

Tags: matplotlib

I am running into an issue in trying to make a graph have the scale exaggerated in the lower region to show the data better.

I would like to plot it so that 1000-3000 is the size of the 0-500 range so that you can better see the data from 0 - 500.

I would like it broken down in [0,100,200,300,400,500, 2000, 3000]

I have tried the following code with no luck:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [0, 100,200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000]
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(len(x)))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(x)

plt.plot(df_run_curves_rhc_60["Iteration"],df_run_curves_rhc_60["Fitness"], label="RHC", color="blue")
plt.plot(df_run_curves_sa_60["Iteration"],df_run_curves_sa_60["Fitness"], label="SA", color="orange")
plt.plot(df_run_curves_ga_60["Iteration"],df_run_curves_ga_60["Fitness"], label="GA", color="green")
plt.plot(df_run_curves_mimic_60["Iteration"],df_run_curves_mimic_60["Fitness"], label="MIMIC", color="yellow")
plt.title("Flip Flop Fitness vs iterations - Size 60 - Max Attempts 200")

plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.ylabel("Fitness Score")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Below is the original image of the graph for reference.
[image: Graph for Reference]

Here is what this code generates:
[image: Code image that was generated]

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a custom `xscale`, where matplotlib actually allows you to specify a custom scaling.

The documentation has some examples, and perhaps the square/sqrt scaling would be a good fit here
https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/scales/scales.html

```py
def forward(x):
    return x**(1/2)

def inverse(x):
    return x**2

# Some fake data
x = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000]
y = [0, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1400, 1500, 1500]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))
plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: example with scaled x axis]
You can of course do additional things like customizing tickmarks etc.
I found the need to set the x limits manually after scaling, else matplotlib decided to crop the image.